# Wrong ordering for APA style bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have an APA style bibliography in my paper and I have a paper written by the "Académie des Sciences". I expect it to be on the top of the list of references as I'm citing it like this:

```
author = { \relax{Académie des sciences}, },
```

That is, basically the written output is `Académie des sciences` but it stays in the next page after letter P and letter R (as if it was indexed with the "s" of sciences).

How can I make sure that it stays on the top? That is it gets printed as `Académie des sciences` but it stays on the top of the bibliography list?

Thank you!

Comment: As it's a "corporate" author, it must be entered as `author = {{Académie des sciences}},`.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct!

Comment: Actually, the question about how to input a "corporate" author in the author field has come up quite a few times on this site. The site rules thus indicated that it should be closed as a duplicate. Please don't feel bad, though, about posting a query that turns out to be duplicate. If anything, it demonstrates the importance and broad relevance of your query.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know this was called a "corporate" author! I would have otherwise looked for it!